# Improve performance of php on local server

Tags: php, performance, xampp

I have a XAMPP install, with pretty much the default config.

Performance isn't much of a problem in general as I use PHP mostly to run web pages and small web apps. Waiting a couple seconds for a page is not unusual.

However, I have recently taken up the problems from Project Euler and decided to do them in PHP.

Try as I may, I couldn't get my code to run in less than 1 minute 1 second (optimized down from almost 3 min) and I was getting pretty embarrassed, especially considering most posters on Pjt Euler reported times of 1-3 seconds. (#7, find the 10001th prime)

I ported my code to C#, and the same task completed in a blink. 0.4 seconds. Same algorithm, the only notable difference in the code is that I used a List in C# to replace the array I was using in PHP.

While I did expect C# to outperform php, this difference leads me to suspect a gross configuration problem, but I have no idea where to look.

What could be the cause of this poor performance?

---

Edit: Here is the code:

**In PHP:**

```
/*
  * Project Euler #7:
  * By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can see that the 6th prime is 13.
  * What is the 10001st prime number?
  */

ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);  
echo "start time:" . date("i:s:u") . "<br />";
function isPrime($number, $prevPrimes)
{       
    foreach ($prevPrimes as $key =>$prime)
    {
        if ($prime == 1)
        {
            continue;
        }
        elseif ($number % $prime == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    // If we get to here, $number is prime
    return $number; 
}
$primes = array();
$i = 0;
$nbPrimes = 0;
while ($nbPrimes <10001)
{
    $i++;
    if ($i % 2 != 0)
    {
        $result = isPrime($i, $primes);

        if ($result != 0)
        {
            $primes[] = $i;
            $nbPrimes++;
        }
    }
}
echo "#$nbPrimes: $result<br>";

echo "End time:" . date("i:s:u") . "<br />";
```

**In C#:**

```
public static void RunSnippet()
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    List<int> primes = new List<int>();
    int i = 0;
    int nbPrimes = 0;
    int result =0;
    while (nbPrimes <10001)
    {
        i++;
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            result = isPrime(i, primes);

            if (result != 0)
            {
                primes.Add(i);
                nbPrimes++;
            }
        }
    }
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}",
    stopwatch.Elapsed);
    Console.WriteLine ("#" + nbPrimes + ": " + result.ToString());
}
public static int isPrime(int number, List<int> prevPrimes)
{
    foreach (int prime in prevPrimes)
    {
        if (prime == 1)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (number % prime == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    // If we get to here, number is prime
    return number;  
}
```

Comment: try posting the server related question on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Here you go. I assumed that since the algorithm is the same, the code itself would not be a big factor.

Comment: @Sylverdrag well, there are some no-gos you can do in PHP that would explain a certainly higher execution time, unfortunately T don't see any of them here, anyhow, do you have APC or any other opcode Cache enabled? (could help here)

Comment: @G Molvi: I considered it, but as I am not sure if the issue is my configuration or my code or PHP itself, I thought it would belong here.

Comment: @G Molvi: I don't think this belongs on serverfault.  @Sylverdrag, I just tested the code (PHP version) on my Linux via PHP CLI, and yea, its about a 30 second, give or take 5 seconds execution time. Taking apache out of the equation may have accounted for the better time, but I am also not running XAMP. And as far as C# doing it much quicker, well it is a compiled language, but the margin is pretty extensive, and yea, I am interested to see if PHP can come closer to it or not.

Comment: @Sylverdrag you can slightly increase the performance by changing `==`to `===` and largely by passing `$prevPrimes` as reference http://pastebin.com/C2z7vUj5

Comment: @Brad: Thanks for testing. Yeah, I expect having to go through Apache accounts for the difference in perf, and possibly the fact that I am on a laptop (i3 2.4Ghz), but still from 0.4s to 30s... there has to be something wrong here.

Comment: @Hannes: Waow! This gets the running time down to 28 seconds!

Comment: @Hannes: Forgot to answer re: APC. I just turned it on. It doesn't seem to make a difference (27 seconds on my last try).

Comment: @Sylverdrag  don't mention it - should ppl have posted it :D ah, nvm, Brad F Jacobs needs the points (j/k)

Comment: @Hannes, I am more then willing to share if you want to post it up as well. :)

Comment: Does changing `foreach ($prevPrimes as $key =>$prime)` to `foreach ($prevPrimes as $prime)` help?

Comment: @Salman A: It does not appear to, I did in the code I posted just because it is an extra variable. But just tested and yea, same time as with `$key`.

Comment: and does replacing `foreach ($prevPrimes as $key =>$prime){` with `for($i = 0, $j = count($prevPrimes); $i < $j; $i++){$prime = $prevPrimes[$i];` help?

Comment: @Salman A: that is worse. Went from 6 seconds to 36 seconds.

Comment: @Salman A benchmarks I've seen place foreach as the best performing array iteration loop.

Comment: PHP uses hash maps for its arrays. It will always be slower given the current version of PHP.

Comment: @dqhendricks: you're right, just found out :/

Comment: @Hannes: Yeah, you should have posted, it was a really nice catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FINAL EDIT**

Here is the PHP code from Bakudan's logic, which returns this result:

```
start time:44:25:000000
#10001: 104759
End time:44:26:000000
```

**The Code:**

```
<?php
echo "start time:" . date("i:s:u") . "\n";

function isPrime($number, &$primes)
{
    if ($number === 1) return false;
    elseif ($number %2 === 0) return false;
    elseif ($number < 4) return true;
    elseif ($number < 9) return true;
    elseif ($number %3 === 0) return false;
    else $r = floor(sqrt($number));

    $f = 5;
    while ($f <= $r) {
        if ($number % $f ===0) return false;
        if ($number % ($f+2) === 0) return false;
        $f = $f + 6;
    }

    return true;
}

$primes = array();
$nbPrimes = $i = 0;
while ($nbPrimes < 10001)
{
    $i++;
    if (isPrime($i, $primes) !== false)
    {
        $primes[] = $i;
        $nbPrimes++;
    }
}
echo "#$nbPrimes: " . end($primes) . "\n";
echo "End time:" . date("i:s:u") . "\n";
```

Bakudan gave me the pseudo code, I Just translated and wrote it out for the OP's script above.

---

**EDIT 2**

I cleaned up the code a bit, didn't improve anything, may enhance "readability". But yea, I think this is the best you will get with PHP, which on an i7 without apache yields 5 seconds.

```
    <?php
    echo "start time:" . date("i:s:u") . "\n";

    function isPrime($number, &$primes)
    {
        foreach($primes as $prime) {
            if ($number % $prime === 0 && $prime > 1)
                    return false;
        }
    }

    $primes = array();
    $nbPrimes = $i = 1;
    while ($nbPrimes <= 10001)
    {
        if ($i % 2 !== 0 && isPrime($i, $primes) !== false)
        {
            $primes[] = $i;
            $nbPrimes++;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    echo "#$nbPrimes: " . end($primes) . "\n";
    echo "End time:" . date("i:s:u") . "\n";
```

---

**EDIT**

Knocked another second off by moving the `$prime === 1` to be after the `$number % $prime` check in the same `if` statement.

```
start time:29:40:000000
#10001: 104743
End time:29:45:000000
```

---

Taking Hannes suggestion of strict checking and passing the array as reference plus adding a few tweaks of my own (modifying the array inside the function):

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
echo "start time:" . date("i:s:u") . "\n";

function isPrime($number, &$prevPrimes)
{
   foreach ($prevPrimes as $prime) {
        if ($number % $prime === 0 && $prime !== 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // If we get to here, $number is prime
    $prevPrimes[] = $number;
    return $number;
}

$primes = array();
$i = 0;
$nbPrimes = 0;
while ($nbPrimes < 10001)
{
    $i++;
    if ($i % 2 !== 0)
    {
        $result = isPrime($i, $primes);

        if ($result !== 0)
        {
            $nbPrimes++;
        }
    }
}
echo "#$nbPrimes: $result\n";

echo "End time:" . date("i:s:u") . "\n";
```

Which ended up being:

```
start time:52:08:000000
#10001: 104743
End time:52:15:000000
```

VS your code:

```
start time:50:44:000000
#10001: 104743
End time:51:17:000000
```

A good improvement there, but nothing like C#, just goes to show the power of a compiled language :)

Comment: Thanks. Combining the $prime === 1 with "if" is a good optimization. It's now down to 23 seconds (through Apache). In C#, it also gives a slight boost in speed (0.41s =>0.40s), whereas passing by reference gives the same result (probably already optimized by the compiler). I am going to wait for a day or so before approving the answer, just in case there is another optimization suggested. So far this question has been a goldmine for me.

Comment: No worries. It just intrigued me and I found it fun :) Glad it helped, I am still working on improving it, but running out of ideas. If I stumble on something more I will update.

Answer (score 5):

"Use the **force** ..." of **math**! Just throwing some code pointless. Here are just a few points that can boost the performance.

- why you are using array to match the number against?
- the foreach function is thus ineffective - the cycle should end at `floor(sqrt(number))`

  example: sqrt(64) = 8 -> all prime dividers will be from 1 to 8. The others will be product of them( 32 = 4 x 8 = 2x2x2x2x2 )
- use formulas to jump to the next possibly prime number

  math:

  numbers divisable by 2 - 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 -> 2k+1 = 2x1+1 = 3, 5, .....

  numbers divisable by 3 - 3, **6**, 9, **12** -> we already have 6 and 12, so 3, 9, 15, 21 -> 3(2k-1) = 3(2x1-1) = 3, 9, ...

here is some [pseudo code](http://projecteuler.net/project/resources/007_c1bfcd3425fd13f6e9abcfad4a222e35/007_overview.pdf) from [hk](http://projecteuler.net/profile/hk.png) admin at project euler

```
isPrime ( number )
{
    if ( number == 1 )      return false
    elseif ( number < 4 )       return true
    elseif ( number % 2 == 0 )  return false
    elseif ( number < 9 )       return true
    elseif ( number % 3 == 0 )  return false
    else
        r = floor ( sqrt ( number ) ) 
    f = 5
    while ( f <= r )
    {
        if ( number % f == 0 ) return false
        if ( number % ( f + 2 ) == 0 ) return false
        f = f + 6
    }
    return true
}
```

PS

About the difference in the speed of the execution - PHP is interpreted language, <strike>to view the result in browser you have 3 programs running - browser, server, php interpreter. You make a http request, the server calls php (and probably a bunch of other stuff, logging for example),</strike>php reads the script and executes it. There are much more steps than in C#.

In C# the compiled code is executed.

Comment: @Bakudan: Thanks. I will look into that. However, the real question here concerns the difference of performance between this code in php and the same code in C#. I am not particularly worried about finding the most efficient method of calculating primes, I am interested in finding out what makes PHP perform faster or at least not so dismally slow.

Comment: @Bakudan: Thanks. From my understanding, a request is sent from the browser to the Apache server. The request is then sent to the php interpreter. The PHP interpreter then runs the script (including the timer calls), then sends the result back to Apache which sends them to the browser. In other words, the timing occurs only at the php interpreter and does not include the time necessary for the http round trip. If this is this correct, I don't see how the browser-Apache sequence would add to the running time of the script. Am I missing something big in the way PHP runs on a wamp stack?

Comment: @Sylverdrag I mean with the 3 programs running you have more memory usage and processor time usage.

Comment: @Bakudan: Oh that. But the same is true for the c# script. same programs running. Either way, at no point is the CPU or the memory fully used, so it shouldn't be the limit. PHP causes quite a spike, but it doesn't max out on any of the cores. C# doesn't even register

Comment: @Slyverdrag, C# does not have to go through those programs. They may be running in the background, but C# is not dependent on them and does not make use of them. Compiling the program, like C# does, makes vasts improvements, as PHP is a scripting language, not compiled. So it's code has to be translated by the compiler each run. Where as C# it only had to be translated once. There are ways to compile PHP, I believe HipHop (http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=280583813919) is one way. You may venture down that road and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Bakudan, nice. I just set it up and yea, its under a second for that to return. Great information.

Comment: @Bakudan: what do you mean by "each run"? I don't understand why CPU would be a limit if it is not used fully. I don't understand why the browser and the server would add a delay, if the timer runs only when the script run and stops at the script end. Whatever time is necessary for the server & browser to do their thing should occur either before the timer starts or after the timer stops, and as such never enter in the computation. what am I missing here? As you can see, there are still a lot of things I don't understand here.

Comment: They should add at lest a little delay because you do not have a cpu for each program. They share the cpu resource. But the most important reason for the difference is because php is interpreted. Try to run the script from the console. If there is no difference, I`m wrong.

Comment: @Bakudan: Sorry, it looks like you are wrong. I get 23 seconds either way. I guess this means that PHP is just not suited for this kind of things.

Comment: Ok, my mistake. Every language should have its chance. If you optimize it it will get fast enough.

Comment: @Sylverdrag: Long story short: PHP is not intended for number crunching. The number crunching algorithms are best implemented in PHP core or inside an extension DLL. PHP is an interpreted language, not a compiled language. In a compiled language, `a = 0` translates to less than 10 instructions for the CPU. In an interpreted language such as PHP, `$a = 0` translates to a **whole lot** more than that. @Bakudan: console or not, PHP remains interpreted.

Answer (score 2):

> While I did expect C# to outperform
>   php, this difference leads me to
>   suspect a gross configuration problem,
>   but I have no idea where to look.

Firing the PHP engine creates a little overhead for the webserver. The way PHP is loaded (e.g. loaded as a module on server startup or loaded on demand for every .php request) determines how much overhead is involved. Then on windows there are two variants of PHP available: thread-safe and non thread-safe, the latter one is claimed to be faster.

If its a XAMPP configuration problem, I think you can isolate it by running the test 3 times on your webserver and note down the average time. Then run the same script via *PHP CLI* 3 times and note down the average. If the difference is noticeable then you might blame XAMPP. You should be able to locate the PHP CLI binary somewhere inside the XAMPP installation folder.

On my system I get these results:

```
PHP-CLI:            #10001: 104743 -- Time taken: 30.25 second(s)
PHP on IIS/FastCGI: #10001: 104743 -- Time taken: 29.89 second(s)
PHP on Apache/CGI:  #10001: 104743 -- Time taken: 29.93 second(s)
```

Not much of a difference -- I would rather optimize the code.

## EDIT

Same machine and everything but execution time brought down from ~30 seconds to ~5.85 seconds with this revised code. The only thing worth mentioning is that that I used a global array instead of passing it by value every time the isPrime function is called (104743 times to be precise). Passing the array by reference also results in similar execution time, give or take 1 second. The comparison operators shave off just a second or two but not much.

```
/*
 * Project Euler #7:
 * By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can see that the 6th prime is 13.
 * What is the 10001st prime number?
 */
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);  
$t0 = microtime(true);
$primes = array();
function isPrime($number)
{       
    global $primes;
    foreach ($primes as $prime)
    {
        if ($prime === 1)
        {
            continue;
        }
        elseif ($number % $prime === 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return $number; 
}
$i = 0;
$nbPrimes = 0;
while ($nbPrimes < 10001)
{
    $i++;
    if ($i % 2 !== 0)
    {
        $result = isPrime($i);
        if ($result !== 0)
        {
            $primes[] = $i;
            $nbPrimes++;
        }
    }
}
$t1 = microtime(true);
echo sprintf('#%d: %d -- Time taken: %.2f second(s)', $nbPrimes, $result, $t1 - $t0);
```